# Will sitting for the IELTS Academic module void the validity of my previous General Training module score?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language-exams, ielts

I have already taken the IELTS GT examination and my score has not yet expired. If I take the IELTS academic exam, will my previous score be voided? I need to take both format of exams for different purposes.

Comment: I think this is a specific question about the IELTS system and not a general question about academia.

Comment: Questions related to graduate admissions __are__ considered on-topic, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the best information you could [Contact IELTS](http://www.ielts.org/contact_us/online_enquiry.aspx)

That said, from reading the [information booklet](http://www.ielts.org/PDF/IELTS%20Information%20for%20Candidates%202014.pdf) (pages 3-5) on their website the two tests have some sections that apply to the both GT and Academic tests which are speaking and listening. They then have 2 modules that are different for each test, which are reading and writing.

They are also used for two different purposes

> IELTS Academic is for test takers wishing to study at undergraduate or postgraduate levels, and for those seeking professional registration.
>
> IELTS General Training is for test takers wishing to migrate to an English-speaking country (Australia, Canada, New Zealand, UK), and for those wishing to train or study at below degree level

From this it would seem unusual that the results from one test would void the other when they are both different tests.

**Edit based on OP comment:**
After the OP contacted IELTS thay said that 'they are both separate results and it will be your choice entirely which one you wish to present when applying to institution's.' which confirms that one test would not void the other.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your link. This is what they replied to me - "In answer to your question about the results they are both separate results and it will be your choice entirely which one you wish to present when applying to institution's."

Comment: @enthusiast You can post this comment as an answer to your own question.